# Very large float in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, floating-point, decimal

I'm trying to construct a neural network for the Mnist database. When computing the softmax function I receive an error to the same ends as "you can't store a float that size"

code is as follows:

```
def softmax(vector): # REQUIRES a unidimensional numpy array 
    adjustedVals = [0] * len(vector)
    totalExp = np.exp(vector)
    print("totalExp equals")
    print(totalExp)
    totalSum = totalExp.sum()
    for i in range(len(vector)):
        adjustedVals[i] = (np.exp(vector[i])) / totalSum
    return adjustedVals # this throws back an error sometimes?!?!
```

After inspection, most recommend using the decimal module. However when I've messed around with the values being used in the command line with this module, that is:

```
from decimal import Decimal
import math
test = Decimal(math.exp(720))
```

I receive a similar error for any values which are math.exp(>709).

```
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

My conclusion is that even decimal cannot handle this number. Does anyone know of another method I could use to represent these very large floats.

Comment: I think you're using Decimal incorrectly, you're still calling math.exp(720) which is having the same problem of the number of being too large, irrespective of that fact you're going to pass it to decimal, it doesn't know that yet. I think you want Decimal(720).exp()

Answer (score 0):

With a value above 709 the function 'math.exp' exceeds the floating point range and throws this overflow error.

If, instead of `math.exp`, you use `numpy.exp` for such large exponents you will see that it evaluates to the special value `inf` (infinity).

All this apart, I wonder why you would want to produce such a big number (not sure you are aware how big it is. Just to give you an idea, the number of atoms in the universe is estimated to be in the range of 10 to the power of 80. The number you are trying to produce is MUCH larger than that).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've realised now that there was a bug higher up which was causing my first layer to produce such large values. the new values produced are well within a more sensible range (~50-100) - However, I still run into the same issue when feeding these values through to the next layer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique which makes the softmax function more feasible computationally for a certain kind of value distribution in your `vector`. Namely, you can subtract the maximum value in the `vector` (let's call it `x_max`) from each of its elements. If you recall the softmax formula, such operation doesn't affect the outcome as it reduced to multiplication of the result by `e^(x_max) / e^(x_max) = 1`. This way the highest intermediate value you get is `e^(x_max - x_max) = 1` so you avoid the overflow.

For additional explanation I recommend the following article: https://nolanbconaway.github.io/blog/2017/softmax-numpy